# Get ValueFromRemainingArguments as an hashtable

Tags: powershell

Using `[parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]` one can get all the remaining arguments passed to the function into a variable as a list.

How can I get the remaining arguments as a hashtable type, for example for inputs like `Function -var1 value1 -var2 value2`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this. The following solution supports parameters with:

- Simple value (single item)
- Array value
- Null value (switch)

Script:

```
function testf {

    param(
        $name = "Frode",
        [parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
        $vars
    )

    "Name: $name"
    "Vars count: $($vars.count)"
    "Vars:"

    #Convert vars to hashtable
    $htvars = @{}
    $vars | ForEach-Object {
        if($_ -match '^-') {
            #New parameter
            $lastvar = $_ -replace '^-'
            $htvars[$lastvar] = $true
        } else {
            #Value
            $htvars[$lastvar] = $_
        }
    }

    #Return hashtable
    $htvars

}

testf -simplepar value1 -arraypar value2,value3 -switchpar
```

Output:

```
Name: Frode
Vars count: 5
Vars:

Name      Value
----      -----
arraypar  {value2, value3}
switchpar
simplepar value1
```

Edit: Modified default value assigned to Hashtable keys: `$htvars[$lastvar] = $true`. Using `$true` as the default accounts for switch parameters and can make the resulting Hastable more "splattable".

Comment: I believe the initial value assigned to each  key in the Hashtable should be `$true` instead of `$null` to  account for `switch` parameters and produce a splattable hashtable.

Comment: Good point. You're welcome to submit an edit to the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Updated per Ansgars comment.

One possibility is to build the hash-table within the function. Here is an example:

```
function MyFunction
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param([parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)] $allparams)

    process
    {
        $myhash = @{}
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $allparams.count; $i+=2)
        {
            $myhash[($allparams[$i]-replace '^-+')] = $allparams[$i+1]
        }
    }
    end
    {
        $myhash
    }
}
```

We parse through the params in the parameters $allparams using a for loop, and retrieve the key/value pairs to form the hash table, then in the end block we display it.

```
MyFunction -var1 10 -var2 30 -var3 hello

Name                          Value                     
----                          -----                     
var1                          10                        
var3                          hello                     
var2                          30
```

Comment: I'd change 2 things: a) use `($allparams[$i] -replace '^-+')` instead of `.Replace('-','')`, because the latter would turn a parameter `-Some-Thing` into `SomeThing` instead of `Some-Thing`, b) use `$myhash[$key] = $value` instead of `$myhash.Add($key, $value)`, because the latter throws an error when a parameter appears more than once whereas the former updates its value.

Comment: I adapted this into a helper function `Get-ParamHash` that expects `[string[]]$ParamArray`. When calling it inside a recursive function that defines its own `[parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)][string[]]$ParamArray` to pass into `Get-ParamHash`, I had to add `-replace ':$'` after the `-replace '^-+'` to prevent colon stacking. It seems that splatting a hashtable adds a colon to the key for consistency.

Answer (score 2):

This is tricky because using [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)] means this is an advanced function, and $args cannot be used in advanced functions.

But if you want a hashtable of all the specified parameters and their values, you could simply use $PSBoundParameters, like so :

```
function foo {
    [cmdletbinding()]

    param( 
        [Parameter(Position=0)]       
        $Name,

        [Parameter(Position=1,ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
        $LastName
    )

    "PSBoundParameters : " 
    $PSBoundParameters

}
foo -Name Mike Jordan Jones
```

This results in the following :

```
PSBoundParameters : 

Key                                               Value                                           
---                                               -----                                           
Name                                              Mike                                            
LastName                                          {Jordan, Jones}
```

Is this what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: Good solution, but it only supports "known parameters", and it seemed that he wanted to catch unknown parameters that some clever IT admin might try. :)  Personally, I think he should define every possible parameter as optional parameters at the "end" (high position value). In some way, he has to handle the unknown parameters in the code anyways.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of caveats with this method but I just wanted to show that `ConvertFrom-StringData` could also be considered here.

```
function Convert-StringToHashTable {

    param(
        [parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
        [string]$string
    )

    $string -replace "(^| )-","`r`n" | ForEach-Object{$_ -replace "(\w+) (.*)",'$1=$2'} | ConvertFrom-StringData
}

Convert-StringToHashTable -var1-5 value1 -var2 "value2 or 3"
```

Output from above would be

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                        
----                           -----                                                                                                                                        
var2                           value2 or 3                                                                                                                                      
var1-5                         value1
```

We take the all the remaining arguments as a single string. Then we split the string on `-` that occur at the beginning of the line or after a space. ( This accounts for dashes in the middle of works like Ansgar mentioned in another answer). Then we convert the first space after the first word into an equal sign. That will make a string of key value pairs that `ConvertFrom-StringData` expects.

**Known Caveats**

1. This will not work if you try to send arrays like in Frode's answer. He can handle those.