# Powershell: how to pass an array of arguments to a function where they will be applied on a command

Tags: powershell, arguments

I want to make a function TestPathAndRemoveDirectory. I want to test if a directory exists before I try to delete it with Remove-Item so no error message is shown when the folder is already deleted.

What I want to do but not able to achieve is the following:

```
function TestPathAndRemoveDirectory{
    param(    
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $path          
    )

    Remove-Item -path $path $args
}

TestPathAndRemoveDirectory 'C:\ProgramData\Prodata Mobility Systems\Logs\' -Recurse -Force
```

So I want to take in a mandatory path to the folder I need to delete and then just re-use the `-Recurse` and `-Force` arguments on the `Remove-Item`.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you just want to stop error messages from displaying, you could set `$ErrorActionPreference="SilentlyContinue"`

Comment: Thanks, but that looks to much of a hack for what i want to be achieving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar finding to that of Joey but depending on what you are willing to do you can still [splat](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx) as long as you pass a hashtable of you arguments as an optional argument. I will show a non destructive example with `GetChild-Item`

```
function Get-Bagels{
    param(    
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $Path,
         [hashtable]$dynamicArgs
    )

    Get-ChildItem $path @dynamicArgs
}
```

With a sample function call

```
Get-Bagels 'C:\temp\'  @{"File"=$true;"Filter"="*.txt"}
```

You don't even have to specify anything. It will work if you omit the table as well. Just make sure you use `@{"Recurse"=$true;"Force"=$true}` or something similar when you call `Remove-Item`. Essentially you can pass as much or as little as you want.

---

I had forgetten that [I had already seen something like this before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27764394/get-valuefromremainingarguments-as-an-hashtable/27767211#27767211). So if you are willing to have a *little* extra code in your function....

```
function Get-Bagels{
    param(    
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $Path,
         [parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$True)]
         $dynamicArgs
    )

    If($dynamicArgs){
        $props = @{}
        $dynamicArgs | ForEach-Object{
            If($_ -match "^-"){
                # This is a parameter name
                $props.$($_ -replace "^-") = $null
            } Else {
                # This is a parameter value and assign it to last name
                $props.$(([string[]]$props.Keys)[-1]) = $_
            }
        }
    }

    Get-ChildItem $path @props
}

Get-Bagels 'C:\temp\' -File -Filter "*.txt"
```

This will take the remaining arguments and convert them into a hashtable which is then splatted just like my code above.

This was tested with switches and string arguments which is what you have as examples. It *should* work for other data types so as always testing it key. If you looked at the linked question the accepted answer allows for arrays as well but does not discuss splatting.

Comment: Yeah, that would have been my suggestion as well. It's just quite ugly to write, sadly.

Comment: Okay thanks, this answer shows me it's not possible the way I imagened it would be, but it shows the closest solution to that, a not very elegant one so I will probably use Joey's suggestion

Comment: @S.Robijns If you are still here I updated the post with what you were looking for.

Comment: Nice, this is eventually what i wanted, to be able to call My function the same way i would call Remove-Item (in your codesample Get-ChildItem) with its arguments.

Comment: I think string arguments *may* be converted to their proper type upon parameter binding, which should happen when splatting. So the restriction to string and switch parameters isn't necessarily a restriction here.

Answer (score 2):

Just define the missing parameters on the function as well and pass them to `Remove-Item`:

```
function TestPathAndRemoveDirectory{
    param(    
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $Path,
         [switch] $Recurse,
         [switch] $Force
    )

    Remove-Item -path $path -Recurse:$Recurse -Force:$Force
}
```

Usually if you want to force an object to be used as a bunch of bound parameters you need to use the splat operator, e.g. `@args` instead of `$args`. However, in a quick test, this will not work here either, so you need to pass them manually. Parameter binding already fails for your function because there is no `-Recurse` or `-Force` parameter, so it already stops working a step earlier than you think your problem is.

Comment: Yeah, this was kind of my back-up plan. Unfortunately this requires me to define all those parameters that Remove-Item has in my function as well. I hoped there would be a dynamic way to pass on a random bunch of parameters

Comment: I was about to suggest what Matt offered in his answer as a fallback. But that still means you cannot pass parameters as usual, but have to wrap them in a hash table. If you want PowerShell parameter binding, then you have to declare those parameters, otherwise it just cannot work.

Comment: @Joey Not the prettiest thing but I updated my answer to convert basic remaining arguments to a hashtable. Works with basic data types.