# How to allow unspecified named parameters?

Tags: powershell

I'd like to allow the caller of a PowerShell function I'm writing to pass named parameters not specified by me, and then be able to get them into a hashtable. This is in order to specify the properties of an object that's similar to `PSCustomObject`, but not identical. I need to do a little processing around setting these properties, so I can't just have the caller do it themselves and pass me the object.

I could just take a hashtable (and that's my current stopgap solution), but it'd be far more elegant to do it this way.

Comment: I doubt you can; parameters are handled by the PowerShell engine and when it tries to bind `-Foo test` and the function has no declared `Foo` parameter, the PowerShell engine will throw `A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Foo'.` before your cmdlet runs. I comment rather than answer because there might be a way to use DynamicParameters but even then I think they only let you generate a list of parameters for the PS engine to work with, they don't bring parameter handling into your function. Or you could accept one `[string]` and parse it all yourself..

Comment: Does the solution here work?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27764394/get-valuefromremainingarguments-as-an-hashtable

Comment: Yes, that should work. Thank you.