# Require and test for named arguments only

Tags: powershell

I have a script that is intended to take named arguments, and I would like to provide some error checking in the case of unnamed or misnamed arguments, and I am seeing some weirdness.

The script starts with a parameter block, like this

```
param (
    [string][Alias("s")]  $sets,
    [string][Alias("l")]  $location, # /MLF #
    [switch][Alias("c")]  $conform,

    [string][Alias("eM")] $exitMode,
    [string][Alias("iM")] $interactionMode,
    [string][Alias("lM")] $logMode,
    [switch][Alias("tM")] $testMode,

    [parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments = $true)][object[]]$extraParameters = @()
)
```

And I can then use this to take the array of extraneous argument data and strip out the values, so I can provide the user a list of extraneous or misnamed parameters. All good.

```
if ($extraparameters.count -gt 0) {
    $invalidArguments = New-Object Collections.ArrayList
    foreach ($namedParameter in $extraParameters) {
        if ($namedParameter.StartsWith('-')) {
            $invalidArguments.Add($namedParameter) > $null
        }
    }
    Write-PxLog "{initError-[cf][2]}_Invalid arguments '$($invalidArguments -join ', ')'"
    $proceed = $false
}
```

Later I also validate the values of some parameters, such as here where I provide a default log mode if no log mode is provided, validate a provided log mode, and log an error if the log mode isn't an allowed value. All working.

```
if ($logMode) {
    if ($validLogMode = Resolve-PxLogMode $logMode) {
        $logMode = $validLogMode
    } else {
        Write-PxLog "{initError-[cf][2]}_Invalid -logMode '$($logMode)'"
        $logMode = $null
        $proceed = $false
    }
} else {
    $logMode = 'Terse'
}
```

All of this is with named arguments as expected, so the command line might be

```
sets:Proxy -logMode:Verbose -eM:exitConsole
```

Still all good.

However, when I try to validate against unnamed arguments it all falls apart. If I use this at the command line

```
Proxy exitConsol verbose
```

I would expect `$args.count` to be 3, and I would expect exitMode, interactionMode and logMode to default. But `$args.count` is 0, and even weirder, exitMode validates against 'verbose'. My assumption here is the Conform parameter, being a switch, throws it off so $exitMode takes the third provided string.

So, how can I force named parameters, and test for unnamed ones so I can provide a meaningful error? I expected $args to do the trick, but it seems if you use a Param() block $args isn't populated, and a parameter that doesn't specify a position can still be a positional parameter, and using `(Position=#)` simply allows that position to be defined as different from the order the parameters themselves are defined?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get ValueFromRemainingArguments as an hashtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27764394/get-valuefromremainingarguments-as-an-hashtable)

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, as that link is all about getting NAMED arguments and values into a hash table, and my question is about dealing with and/or blocking UNNAMED arguments. In any case, it seems that PowerShell still has no way to make named arguments mandatory, and I will just work around that fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting together [AdminOfThings' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55044910/3439404) and [Frode F.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/702944/frode-f)'s [answer to *Get ValueFromRemainingArguments as an hashtable*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27765140/3439404):

```
[CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$false)]
param (
    [string][Alias("s")]  $sets,
    [string][Alias("l")]  $location, # /MLF #
    [switch][Alias("c")]  $conform,

    [string][Alias("eM")] $exitMode,
    [string][Alias("iM")] $interactionMode,
    [string][Alias("lM")] $logMode,
    [switch][Alias("tM")] $testMode,

    [parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments)][object[]]$extraParameters = @()
)
    #Convert extraparameters to an OrderedDictionary (initially hashtable)
    $htvars = [ordered]@{}
    $iii = 0                   # extraparameters counter
    $lastvar = "unnamed_$iii"
    $extraparameters | ForEach-Object {
        $iii += 1 
        if($_ -match '^-') {
            #New parameter
            $lastvar = $_ -replace '^-'
            $htvars[$lastvar] = $null
        } else {
            #Value
            $htvars[$lastvar] = $_
            $lastvar = "unnamed_$iii" 
        }
    }
    #Propagate OrderedDictionary
    $htvars
```

Above solution supports parameters with:

- Simple value (single item)
- Array value
- Null value (switch)
- Unnamed value

**Sample output:**

```
PS D:\PShell> .\SO\55042084a.ps1 -a111 -s 555 -abc "ABC" -num 15, 17 'ghi' -Seria "seria" "fifi" -l "llllů" -foo

Name                           Value                                           
----                           -----                                           
a111                                                                           
abc                            ABC                                             
num                            {15, 17}                                        
unnamed_5                      ghi                                             
Seria                          seria                                           
unnamed_8                      fifi                                            
foo                                                                            

PS D:\PShell> .\SO\55042084a.ps1 a111 -s 555 -abc "ABC" -num 15, 17 'ghi' -foo -Seria "seria" "fifi" -l "llllů"

Name                           Value                                           
----                           -----                                           
unnamed_0                      a111                                            
abc                            ABC                                             
num                            {15, 17}                                        
unnamed_5                      ghi                                             
foo                                                                            
Seria                          seria                                           
unnamed_9                      fifi
```

Answer (score 3):

To require that all parameter values except `$extraParameters` be entered with their names, you can simply add the attribute `[CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$false)]` before the `param` keyword:

```
[CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$false)]
param (
    [string][Alias("s")]  $sets,
    [string][Alias("l")]  $location, # /MLF #
    [switch][Alias("c")]  $conform,

    [string][Alias("eM")] $exitMode,
    [string][Alias("iM")] $interactionMode,
    [string][Alias("lM")] $logMode,
    [switch][Alias("tM")] $testMode,

    [parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments = $true)][object[]]$extraParameters = @()
)
```

To access the parameters passed to the function or command, you should use the following inside of your code:

```
$PSBoundParameters
```

#### Explanation

```
[CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$false)]
```

- By default all parameters are **positional**.
- The `PositionalBinding` argument of the `CmdletBinding` attribute
  allows you to control the default setting. If you do not use the
  argument, then you have effectively set `PositionalBinding` to
  `$true`. Leaving the value `$true` will allow unnamed parameters to
  be passed to your command.

`$PSBoundParameters`

- `$PSBoundParameters` contains a dictionary of the parameters passed into your command or script. It can only be accessed from within the scope where the parameters are declared.
- The variable or dictionary will list the parameters that have been declared using the `param` keyword.
- Parameters and parameter values can be accessed using a named index. If you have declared a parameter named `-computer`, then you can access that value within the function from `$PSBoundParameters['Computer']`.
- To accessed the unnamed parameter values in your code, you would simply use `$PSBoundParameters['extraParameters']`.
- The `[PSBoundParametersDictionary]` object methods and properties can be used here.

`$args`

- Contains an array of values for undeclared parameters, i.e. not using the `param` keyword.

`ValueFromRemainingArguments = $true`

- Having this argument set to true allows for unnamed parameter values to be passed into the command. The values will be assigned to whichever parameter has this argument and disregard the value of `PositionalBinding`.

See [about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-6) and [about_Automatic_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6) for additional explanations and possibilities.

#### Example Using Named Arguments

```
function namedArguments {
[cmdletbinding(PositionalBinding=$false)]
param(
[parameter()][string]$a,
[parameter()][byte]$b,
[parameter()][byte]$c

)

write-host "args is "
$args
write-host "parameters is "
$psboundparameters

}

namedArguments -a "hi" -b 2 -c 3
args is
parameters is

Key Value
--- -----
a   hi
b   2
c   3
```

**Calling the Function Above with Unnamed Parameter Value:**

```
namedArguments -a "test" -b 20 -c 43 "extraparameter"
```

> namedArguments : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts
>   argument 'extraparameter'. At line:1 char:1
>   + namedArguments -a "test" -b 20 -c 43 "extraparameter"
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [namedArguments], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,namedArguments

```
namedArguments "no parameter name"
```

> namedArguments : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts
>   argument 'no parameter name'. At line:1 char:1
>   + namedArguments "no parameter name"
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [namedArguments], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,namedArguments

#### Example Using Named and Unnamed

```
function AllArgumentsWelcome {
[cmdletbinding(PositionalBinding=$false)]
param(
[parameter()][string]$a,
[parameter()][byte]$b,
[parameter()][byte]$c,
[parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments = $true)][string]$d
)

$PSBoundParameters
 if ($PSBoundParameters['d']) { # Checking unnamed parameters
  "$($PSBoundParameters['d']) was not assigned to a named parameter!"
 }
}

AllArgumentsWelcome -a "test" -b 2 -c 3 "no parameter name"

Key Value
--- -----
a   test
b   2
c   3
d   no parameter name
no parameter name was not assigned to a named parameter!
```

- Notice the above example accessing the unnamed parameter values passed to the function.

#### Side Notes

- It is possible to set the `[Parameter(Position=0)]` attribute for all
  of your parameters to gain a similar effect of requiring all
  parameters be named. However, if you only have one parameter in a
  function definition, this will not produce the desired result and the
  sole unnamed parameter will be allowed.

.

Comment: that's getting me closer, but I'm not seeing how to use $PSBoundParameters to identify unnamed arguments. Even when I pass nothing but unnamed arguments, I still get values in $PSBoundParameters. Junk values, and no way to identify them as such. What am I missing here?

Comment: Ah, I guess if $PSBoundParameters has one key, extraParameters, then I know all the parameters where unnamed, and otherwise I will need to look at the value of extraParameters to determine if I have bunk parameters or unnamed. Getting complicated rather fast.

Comment: And I seem to remember reading somewhere that using CmdletBinding breaks return codes, and I will also need this script to return information to a calling job. Looks like I better test that first, before I spend too much time implementing this approach.

Comment: I added more detail to see how to access the unnamed parameters using `$PSBoundParamters`. The same logic could be used to check against named parameters as well.